# Can’t Install APN Profile

Tags: ios, cellular-data

So my iPhone (6s, Verizon) became stuck in a boot loop and I had to restore it to a clean build of iOS 11.0.1 last night. I had no backups of it, because iTunes hasn’t worked with my iPhone for the longest time.

I use Straight Talk for my carrier. Before I wiped my iPhone, I installed a configuration profile back when I setup this phone with ST a couple years ago. It worked fine until I restored my iPhone and now trying to access any webpage over cellular data results in “Could not activate cellular data network”.

Now, I’ve found the website where I can download and install the APN settings again, however upon tapping install the seconds time, it says the profile cannot be installed because there is already an APN profile installed. There isn’t.

I think it’s not letting me install it because either Verizon or Straight Talk won’t let me change carrier settings, but **it needs the APN profile to work**.

I called ST before I posted this and they gave me some nonsense about how I needed to buy a new SIM, because the one I have (and have used for over 2 years without any problems) is linked to a different IMEI. I might have better luck with a different rep, but when this happened to me when I first got my 6s, ST gave me this same link to the profile, I downloaded it, and everything was fine. I think this has more to do with iOS than a carrier.

All I want is a way to install the APN profile, or manually configure the cellular settings so I get data again. I prefer to not use any 3rd-Party apps on my Mac or iPhone.

Update: I’ve tried resetting all network settings and then resetting all setting and it still won’t work. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Last time I have some vague, indefinable carrier issue when I re-jigged a phone, I rang the carrier & they pushed the required setup file from their end. I was back up & running in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is good advice, but I already tried that earlier today before I posted this. I'll edit it into the question. Anyway, ST gave me some nonsense about how I needed to buy a new SIM, because the one I have (and have used with this specific 6s for over 2 years without any problems) is linked to a different IMEI. I might have better luck with a different rep, but when this happened to me when I first got my 6s, ST gave me this same link to the profile, I downloaded it, and everything was fine. I think this has more to do with iOS than a carrier.

Comment: They make you **buy** SIMs?? Cheapskates. Mine happened when I changed my deal but not my phone. They sent me a new SIM [because that's just what they do] but I just kept the old one in the phone. The 'new deal' triggered something that they needed to send a new profile for. I really didn't dig around to see what it was, but they had it fixed in a few mins.

Comment: I’m having the same problem. Got a replacement iPhone 6 and it won’t let me get APN